# Send Session Cookies Using a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I need to send an AJAX request to a secure web service (amazon.com, to be specific) from within a Chrome extension and am hitting an issue with the web server [amazon.com] not receiving the session cookies from the currently logged in user [on the browser].

I have tried using the `fetch` function with `credentials: "include"` which doesn't seem to have sent them.

I've enabled cookie access and used `chrome.cookies.getAll()` to successfully retrieve the cookies, but I cannot inject them into the ajax call as I get `Refused to set unsafe header "cookie"`

Currently, I prefer to use `$.ajax` method through jQuery, but I am willing to use the `fetch` as documented [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) if it is required.

Is this possible?  Or with the recent changes to cross domain requests is this no longer possible?

Comment: AFAIK, to set a cookie header manually you'll have to use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders. As for the cookies, if you log in inside a tab, those cookies are local to that tab so I think you should extract them using a content script from `document.cookie`.